# Finding substring with regex Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

How can I find the specific URL for specific tags if I have this `categoryIdList` and `scripts`, is it possible to get the specific url?

```js
const categoryIdList = ["#travel", "#lifestyle", "#fnb", "#gadget_entertainment", "#dailyneeds", "#others_promo"]

const scripts = `$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#travel").click(function(){                           
                  $("#contentpromolain2").load("ajax.promolainnya.php?product=0&subcat=1");
        });

        $("#lifestyle").click(function(){                                
                  $("#contentpromolain2").load("ajax.promolainnya.php?product=0&subcat=2");
        });

        $("#fnb").click(function(){                              
                  $("#contentpromolain2").load("ajax.promolainnya.php?product=0&subcat=3");
        });

        $("#gadget_entertainment").click(function(){                             
                  $("#contentpromolain2").load("ajax.promolainnya.php?product=0&subcat=4");
        });

        $("#dailyneeds").click(function(){                               
                  $("#contentpromolain2").load("ajax.promolainnya.php?product=0&subcat=5");
        });

        $("#others_promo").click(function(){                             
                  $("#contentpromolain2").load("ajax.promolainnya.php?product=0&subcat=6");
        });

        $("#kartukredit").click(function(){                              
                  $("#contentpromolain2").load("ajax.promolainnya.php?product=1");
        });

        $("#simpanan").click(function(){                                 
                  $("#contentpromolain2").load("ajax.promolainnya.php?product=2");
        });

        $("#others").click(function(){                           
                  $("#contentpromolain2").load("ajax.promolainnya.php?product=3");
        });

        $("#ebanking").click(function(){                                 
                  $("#contentpromolain2").load("ajax.promolainnya.php?product=4");
        });
});`
```

The result I want is like

```
{
  "#travel": "ajax.promolainnya.php?product=0&subcat=1",
  "#lifestyle": "ajax.promolainnya.php?product=0&subcat=2",
  // etc
}
```

How can I get that result using regex? Or any method in javascript

Thanks

Comment: JavaScritp regexp to match JavaScript? It is unclear exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are generally looking for is this Regex: `"(.*?)"` (https://regex101.com/r/jY8NBp/1)

This will get you every bit between quotation marks, you can then ignore the middle one when creating your object.

Answer (score 2):

With the caveat that **this is an exceptionally fragile approach and relies on a 1:1 mapping of the `#id` to uri in the `.load` method**, a regex that will help you out relies on [capture groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), and might look something like this:

`/\$\(\"#.*\"\)\.click|\.load\(\".*\"\);/g`

See a breakdown of what it's doing here: https://regex101.com/r/hD0zR5/7

You can use that regex in a script to turn a set of matches into an array, with every 2 array items being a key/value pair.

As long as you can guarantee that will be true (every 2 array items are a key/value pair) you can loop through the array and create they object you're looking for.

Since you already have the `categoryIdList` you could use those values to verify the keys when you're creating your object, if desired.

```js
const scripts = `$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#travel").click(function(){                           
                  $("#contentpromolain2").load("ajax.promolainnya.php?product=0&subcat=1");
        });

        $("#lifestyle").click(function(){                                
                  $("#contentpromolain2").load("ajax.promolainnya.php?product=0&subcat=2");
        });

        $("#fnb").click(function(){                              
                  $("#contentpromolain2").load("ajax.promolainnya.php?product=0&subcat=3");
        });

        $("#gadget_entertainment").click(function(){                             
                  $("#contentpromolain2").load("ajax.promolainnya.php?product=0&subcat=4");
        });

        $("#dailyneeds").click(function(){                               
                  $("#contentpromolain2").load("ajax.promolainnya.php?product=0&subcat=5");
        });

        $("#others_promo").click(function(){                             
                  $("#contentpromolain2").load("ajax.promolainnya.php?product=0&subcat=6");
        });

        $("#kartukredit").click(function(){                              
                  $("#contentpromolain2").load("ajax.promolainnya.php?product=1");
        });

        $("#simpanan").click(function(){                                 
                  $("#contentpromolain2").load("ajax.promolainnya.php?product=2");
        });

        $("#others").click(function(){                           
                  $("#contentpromolain2").load("ajax.promolainnya.php?product=3");
        });

        $("#ebanking").click(function(){                                 
                  $("#contentpromolain2").load("ajax.promolainnya.php?product=4");
        });
});`


const urls = {}
const matches = [...scripts.matchAll(/\$\(\"(#.*)\"\)\.click|\.load\(\"(.*)\"\);/g)]

for (let i = 0;i < matches.length;i += 2) {
  urls[matches[i][1]] = matches[i + 1][2]
}

console.log(urls)
```